# html href doesn't link to external URLs or mailto:

Tags: html

I have been having problems with href links. It doesn't matter how I type the URL it always links relative to my website and so doesn't work. Same happens with mailto: links. So, in an attempt to figure it out I wrote the most basic web page imaginable....and it still doesn't work! I have tried every variant of the URL (with and without 'www', with and without 'http') and nothing works. I have code checked using the w3 validator and it has passed. Any ideas what is going wrong?

I am using text editor on a Mac where I've always used notepad on a PC.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Energise My Life</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<a href=“http://www.energisemylife.uk/”>website</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have Word™ non ascii characters as double quotes.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. It's supposed to be. `<a href="mailto:test@test.com">Click me</a>`. Also, you're using special quotations around your `href` you're supposed to use either `''` or `""` around them.

Comment: OS X's TextEdit will automatically convert quotation marks into "smart quotes" and do other typographical substitutions. To turn it off, uncheck the options under Edit > Substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Jorden1337 is right about using the mailto, if you are trying to send a mail link.  But I would try to use 'normal' quotation marks like ones you would get from a text editor like Atom rather than the ones in your sample code that appear to be Word Processor style quotes.

> " instead of “

So your line of code should be:

```
<a href="http://www.energisemylife.uk/">website</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've sorted the options and am using the correct characters now. It is now working. Thanks